# Magento 1.9 - Get Invoice ID on Payment Event

Tags: php, oop, magento, events

In my Magento 1.9 installation I have an observer that observes the event `sales_order_invoice_pay`. When this event triggers I'm attempting to store the invoice's ID in a custom model I've created.

Here's how I'm getting the invoice from the event: `$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();`

However, when I attempt this using: `getId()`, `getData('entity_id')`, `getIncrementId()`, or `getOrigData('entity_id')`, I receive a `null` value.

I can't even seem to get the increment id from the invoice either, I've used, `getIncrementId()`, `getData('increment_id')`.

I'm at a complete loss here.

It's important for me to store this specific invoice id as I'm using it later to load that invoice and create a shipment for items invoiced.

Is there anyway for me to get the ID?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `\Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::pay` method which dispatches the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event is also called in `\Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::capture` the invoice may not be persisted at the time you are observing. Try using event  `sales_order_invoice_save_after` which is dispatched **after** an invoice is saved. The increment should be saved and an id should be set.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately, the event, `sales_order_invoice_save_after` is not available in Magento 1.9 :( So that's kind of why I'm at a loss here.

Comment: What if I created a module and rewrote this to create my own event?

Comment: @RyanScottCady Are you sure? I just checked the method  \Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_afterSave in version 1.9.3. It should still work. I don't have a magento installation here so plz test it in your env. If it is not working add your xml and code to the question plz.

Comment: does it dispatch like a normal event? Because if not that's why I haven't known it could work. So if that's a thing then what would the best way be to only run the observer code once? I've read that that event runs multiple times during a save, this would be highly undesirable for what I need to do. I really need to run the code once it's paid.

Comment: @RyanScottCady depends on what you want to actually do. You are not specific enough. What is your custom model actually doing? Add code and xml to your question.

Comment: Whenever an invoice is created and a customer purchases a product, we send an order to our distributor through an API. I'm storing the Distributor's order number and such in the model. I've also created a queue, that will be run on the cron. The queue will have an order number and make a request to the Distributor for any updated information, like if the item was shipped or a tracking number has been added.

Comment: I've just tried using that event and it seems to be working pretty well! It's not making duplicates so far. I'll keep testing!

Comment: Nice, try savin the order in backend. I think it will be called there as well. But you can custpmize your code and check if you already used the increment id or not. You could add a custom table if needee to have the information if you already processed it or not. There will be a solution for sure.